# Replace instance label with regex

Tags: prometheus

I'm trying to replace the instance label of a given job. I understand that I can do this with the `relabel_config`. But I struggle with the regex and regex replace stuff.

My targets have an obscure target url like `test1.mysite.de`. There are reasons why I can't change these, so I need to do some relabeling.

This is my current config:

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    target_label: instance
    regex: ^test.*
    replacement: server
```

But this relabels the url to `server`. What's my mistake?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Rewriting the target URL from test1.mysite.com to instance1.mysite.com for example. But I'm not sure if my regex is bad or something else.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like:

```
regex: ^test(.*)
replacement: instance$1
```